# How to multiply two image in Python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have an [input](https://ibb.co/VjDhjGg) image and a [mask](https://ibb.co/SmsVnY1) image. I multiply them together but the [resulting](https://ibb.co/pxXzfzt) image is not like input image.

```py
output = input_image[:, :, :] * mask[:, :, :]
```

How can I multiply them together that the output image will be in the format of input image?

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2
import sys

# ============================================================================

input_image= cv2.imread("E:/blob.jpg")
CANVAS_SIZE = base_img.shape

FINAL_LINE_COLOR = (255, 255, 255)
WORKING_LINE_COLOR = (127, 127, 127)

# ============================================================================

class PolygonDrawer(object):
    def __init__(self, window_name):
        self.window_name = window_name # Name for our window

        self.done = False # Flag signalling we're done
        self.current = (0, 0) # Current position, so we can draw the line-in-progress
        self.points = [] # List of points defining our polygon


    def on_mouse(self, event, x, y, buttons, user_param):
        # Mouse callback that gets called for every mouse event (i.e. moving, clicking, etc.)

        if self.done: # Nothing more to do
            return

        if event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
            # We want to be able to draw the line-in-progress, so update current mouse position
            self.current = (x, y)
        elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
            # Left click means adding a point at current position to the list of points
            print("Adding point #%d with position(%d,%d)" % (len(self.points), x, y))
            self.points.append((x, y))
        elif event == cv2.EVENT_RBUTTONDOWN:
            # Right click means we're done
            print("Completing polygon with %d points." % len(self.points))
            self.done = True


    def run(self):
        # Let's create our working window and set a mouse callback to handle events
        cv2.namedWindow(self.window_name)
        cv2.imshow(self.window_name, np.zeros(CANVAS_SIZE, np.uint8))
        cv2.waitKey(1)
        cv2.setMouseCallback(self.window_name, self.on_mouse)

        while(not self.done):
            # This is our drawing loop, we just continuously draw new images
            # and show them in the named window
            # canvas = np.zeros(CANVAS_SIZE, np.uint8)
            canvas = input_image.astype(np.uint8)
            if (len(self.points) > 0):
                # Draw all the current polygon segments
                cv2.polylines(canvas, np.array([self.points]), False, FINAL_LINE_COLOR, 1)
                # And  also show what the current segment would look like
                cv2.line(canvas, self.points[-1], self.current, WORKING_LINE_COLOR)
            # Update the window
            cv2.imshow(self.window_name, canvas)
            # And wait 50ms before next iteration (this will pump window messages meanwhile)
            if cv2.waitKey(50) == 27: # ESC hit
                self.done = True

        # User finised entering the polygon points, so let's make the final drawing
        canvas = np.zeros(CANVAS_SIZE, np.uint8)
        # of a filled polygon
        if (len(self.points) > 0):
            cv2.fillPoly(canvas, np.array([self.points]), FINAL_LINE_COLOR)
        # And show it
        cv2.imshow(self.window_name, canvas)
        # Waiting for the user to press any key
        cv2.waitKey()

        cv2.destroyWindow(self.window_name)
        return canvas

# ============================================================================

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pd = PolygonDrawer("Polygon")
    mask_image = pd.run()

    output = input_image[:, :, :] * mask[:, :, :]

    cv2.imshow("A", output )


    cv2.waitKey(0)
    print("Polygon = %s" % pd.points)
```

Comment: It's a possible duplicate of that question because that has been answered and fixes your problem. But here's the explanation of your mistake: You're multiplying the values by 255. If they were 1 instead, the colors wouldn't change.